# How to place content in variable with wpf Checkbox and powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, checkbox

I'm trying to place an ip in a variable when i make the checkbox checked and use this variable as the ip address in Invoke-SQLCMD.
It seems that the content of the $DB00 stays empty whatever i do.

```
$window.DB00.add_Checked({

    $DB00 = '192.168.1.1'
    [System.Object]$sender = $args[0]
    [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e = $args[1]   

})

$window.DB00.add_Unchecked({

    $DB00 = $null
    #Get-ChildItem variable:\DB00  
    #Remove-Item variable:\DB00
    [System.Object]$sender = $args[0]
    [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e = $args[1]

})

$window.DB00.add_Indeterminate({

    $DB00 = $null
    [System.Object]$sender = $args[0]
    [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e = $args[1]   

})

#Collect Input fields#
$window.Button.add_Click({

    $UserName = $window.UserName.Text.ToString()
    $PassWord = $window.PassWord.Text.ToString()
    $ServerAddress = $DB00
    $DataBase = $window.DataBase.Text.ToString()
    $SQLQuery = $window.Query.Text.ToString()
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -AbortOnError `
        -Username $UserName `
        -Password $PassWord `
        -Database $DataBase `
        -Query $SQLQuery `
        -QueryTimeout 30 `
        -ServerInstance $ServerAddress |
        Out-GridView -Title $DataBase
    [System.Object]$sender = $args[0]
    [System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e = $args[1]

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [scoping](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847849.aspx) issue. When `add_Checked()` code is invoked, it runs in a child scope, meaning that changes made to `$DB00` inside the scriptblock does not affect the value of `$DB00` outside of it.

To illustrate this, try and run the following snippet:

```
$DB00 = 123
&{
  $DB00 = 456
  &{
    $DB00 = 789
  }
}
# What do you think will be printed?
Write-Host $DB00
```

If this is part of a script or a function, you can qualify the variable with the "script" scope name:

```
$script:DB00 = '192.168.1.1'
```

---

You can also use the `*-Variable` cmdlets with the `-Scope` parameter. This allows you to specify a parent scope relative to the current scope:

```
$DB00 = 123
&{
  Set-Variable DB00 -Value 456 -Scope 1
  &{
    $DB00 = 789
  }
}
# What do you think will be printed now? :)
Write-Host $DB00
```

Comment: Very, very nicely put :)

Comment: Hi Mathias, that was the solution for me, thank you very much!!

Comment: [PS C:\Users\master> Write-Host $DB00
456 ]  Nice so you can calculate between the same variables from different scopes :)

Comment: Yes, the general rule is that you can *read* up (access var in parent scope) by default, but once you start to *write* to a variable (assignment, increment etc.), PowerShell hides the variable from the parent scope under a new variable that is local to the current scope - unless you specifically write to a parent scope

Comment: Again many thanks Mathias, i'm new to powershell and i'm impressed by home much is possible